# How can I remove the package oracle-java11-installer-local?

Tags: package-management

```
root@sotiris-X556UQK:~# sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up oracle-java11-installer-local (11.0.4-1~linuxuprising1) ...
Before installing this package,
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,

E.g.:
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle*
sudo apt purge oracle-java11-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Are you sure for the `;` at the end of each command line? Bash doesn't needed them

Answer (score 2):

I went to the directory `/var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local` using the file manager (Nautilus), confirmed it was there and then opened a terminal and typed:

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
```

That seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Using apt from command line

Just use the command

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

If you want to also remove user data and configuration files
1

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

Using --auto-remove parameter will also remove package dependencies.